# How can I match '*' in a regex

Tags: c++, c, regex, operating-system

I am trying to implement regular expression in C, I have the following code to find all the string which contains '*' in it,

```
regex_t regex;
regcomp(&regex, "^[A-Za-z0-9\*]+$", 0);

if (!regexec(&regex, args[j], 0, NULL, 0)) {
    printf("string found");
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? My code is not matching the strings containing '*'. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, the character `\` needs to be escaped. So if you want to escape an regex `*`, you need to do `\\*`. That should fix the problem. Whenever you use the backslash in a string, you need to escape it like that. If you ever need to find it in a string with the regex, you'll need to search for it with `\\\\`.

Comment: still the code is not working, I just need to check whether the string contains '*'.

Comment: The code seems fine. What does `regcomp` return, and what does `args[j]` look like? What type is `args`?

Comment: The string will look like "/home/student/*".

Comment: Then your code works fine. That string doesn't match the expression you designed. It won't be true for all cases, but try testing your expressions here: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pawel's answer, in C++11 you can simplify this using a raw string literal:

```
regcomp(&regex, R"(^[A-Za-z0-9\*]+$)", 0);
```

(if you wanted to use the `()` chars in the regex you'd have to pick another delimiter, of course).